# How to use SPARQL to CONSTRUCT owl:Restriction

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl

I am trying to create OWL restrictions on some instances in my ontology.  These instances are associated to classes via `rdf:type` relationships when they should be some kind of owl restriction.  To solve this, I created a `CONSTRUCT` statement:

```
PREFIX myontology:<http://myontology.org/myonto/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
CONSTRUCT {
  ?entity rdf:type ?owlRestriction .
  ?owlRestriction a owl:Restriction .
  ?owlRestriction owl:onProperty myontology:someRelation .
  ?owlRestriction owl:someValuesFrom ?someClass .
}

WHERE {
  ?owlRestriction a owl:Restriction .
  ?entity a ?class .
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf* myontology:someSuperClass .
}
```

When I run this, however, the restriction created includes every subclass underneath the `myontology:someSuperClass`.  How can I change the above query such that only the classes directly related to my instances via `rdf:type` get changed to restrictions?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `CONSTRUCT` query created `owl:Restriction` relationships appropriately:

```
PREFIX myontology:<http://myontology.org/myonto/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
CONSTRUCT {
  ?entity a [rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
           owl:onProperties myontology:myrelation;
           owl:someValuesFrom ?class] .
  
}

WHERE {
  ?entity a ?class .
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf* myontology:someSuperClass .
}
```